# Google Maps opens after click on MapView v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have been struggling to make the **MapView** not clickable. I hope someone faced this problem too.

Here's my code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
   android:id="@+id/map_header"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="90dp"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:longClickable="false"
   map:liteMode="true"
   map:mapType="normal"
/>
```

Also:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(userLocation)
            .zoom(16)
            .build();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This only happens when I'm using lite mode. On normal mode, it isn't clickable.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you are using it in an activity. You can do the following

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_header);
        mapView.setClickable(false);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Perform action on your map. E.g. Display marker 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.  The way around this is to override the onMapClick listener like so:

```java
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //do nothing, we want to suppress launching Google Maps
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `mapView.setClickable(false)` within `getMapAsync` call back(`onMapReady` method).